# Ruby future buffer?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, concurrency, celluloid

I want to get a bunch a XML and parse them. They are somewhat large.
So I was thinking I could get and parse them in a future like this:(I currently use Celluloid)

```
country_xml = {}
country_pool = GetAndParseXML.pool size: 4, args: [@connection]
countries.each do |country|
   country_xml[country] = country_pool.future.fetch_xml country
end
countries.each do |country|
xml = country_xml[country]
# Do stuff with the XML!
end
```

This would be fine if it weren't that it takes up a lot of memory before it's actually needed.
Ideally I want it to maybe buffer up 3 XML files stop and wait until at least 1 is processed then continue. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The first question is: what is it that's taking up the memory? I will assume it's the prased XML documents, as that seems most likely to me.

I think the easiest way would be to create an actor that will fetch and process the XML. If you then create a pool of 3 of these actors you will have at most 3 requests being processed at once.

In vague terms (assuming that you aren't using the Celluloid registry):

```
class DoStuffWithCountryXml
    include Celluloid
    exclusive :do_stuff_with_country

    def initialize(fetcher)
        @fetcher = fetcher
    end

    def do_stuff_with_country(country)
        country_xml = fetcher.fetch_xml country
        # Do stuff with country_xml
    end

end

country_pool = GetAndParseXML.pool size: 4, args: [@connection]
country_process_pool = DoStuffWithCountryXml.pool size: 3, args: [country_pool]

countries_futures = countries.map { |c| country_process_pool.future.do_stuff_with_country(c) }

countries_stuff = countries_futures.map { |f| f.value }
```

Note that if this is the only place where GetAndParseXML is used then the pool size might as well be the same as the DoStuffWithXmlActor.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a `Pool` at all. You're not benefiting from it. A lot of people seem to feel using a `Future` and a `Pool` together is a good idea, but it's usually worse than using one or the other.

In your case, use `Future` ... but you will also benefit from the upcoming `Multiplexer` features. Until then, do this... use a totally different strategy than has been tried or suggested:

```
class HandleXML
    include Celluloid
    def initialize(fetcher)
        @fetcher = fetcher
    end
    def get_xml(country)
        @fetcher.fetch_xml(country)
    end
    def process_xml(country, xml)
        #de Do whatever you need to do with the data.
    end
 end

 def begin_processor(handler, countries, index)
     data = handler.future.get_xml(countries[index])
     index += 1
     data
 end

 limiter = 3 #de This sets your desired limit.
 country_index = 0
 data_index = 0
 data = {}
 processing = []
 handler = HandleXML.new(@connection)

 #de Load up your initial futures.
 limiter.times {
     processing << begin_processor(handler, countries, country_index)
 }

 while data_index < countries.length
     data[countries[data_index]] = processor.shift.value
     handler.process_xml(countries[data_index],data[countries[data_index]])
     #de Once you've taken out one XML set above, load up another.
     if country_index < countries.length
         processing << begin_processor(handler, countries, country_index)
     end
 end
```

---

The above is just an example of how to do it with `Future` only, handling `3` at a time. I've not run it and it could have errors, but the idea is demonstrated for you.

The code loads up `3` sets of Country XML, then starts processing that XML. Once it has processed one set of XML, it loads up another, until all the country XML is processed.